# In Wordress one author can not see the other's author uploaded images through media library

Tags: images, media-library

My problem is simple to explain, when author 'A' uploads an image, author 'B' can not see them in the media library and via verca. Any idea what could cause this problem? As an administrator i can see the photos from all the users. Each author can see his own images in the media library.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's default Core behavior for the Author role. Authors can only edit and publish their own content - they can't edit others'.

Here are all the [capabilities of Authors](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#author) - you'll notice that 'edit_others_posts' is not in the list of capabilities.

A few ways you can accomplish your goal are:

- Use, or create, a user role plugin that adds the 'edit_others_posts' capability to the Author role
- Make your users Editors instead of Authors
- Create a plugin that adds a new custom role, with the same capabilities as Authors but with 'edit_others_posts' also added

Comment: I made the user editor but still no effect any other idea?